# How to make the most of the Lumia 1020 Camera?

Tags: 8.1, camera, nokia-lumia-1020

The camera is the showpiece of the 1020 but frankly, these "lenses" confuse me. There's a Nokia and Lumia camera app which appear very similar, for a start.

And then I read somewhere that the camera supports HDR but I've never seen any option referencing it.

How should I be using my phone to take best advantage of what is a pretty impressive piece of hardware?